# how to move columns and put in a specific order with the google app script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I would like to change the order of columns in a spreadsheet. For example:

Before
A B C D E

After
C D A E B

I have a list with the indexes of the columns in the desired order like this:

order = [1, 2, 4, 19, 8]

And I would like to go through a list and get the columns with the indexes in the order of that list and put in spreadsheet

Comment: See if this helps: https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/02/10/rearranging-columns-on-google-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script/

Answer (score 2):

This would work for your example.

```
function reorder() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg=sh.getDataRange();
  const vA=rg.getValues();
  vB=vA.map(function(r){
    return [r[2],r[3],r[0],r[4],r[1]];
  });
  rg.setValues(vB);
}
```